# Python League table problems

Tags: python, csv, easygui

I am attempting to make a football league table in Python out of information from the user. The problem I am having is getting `row[6]` (goal difference) and `row[7]` (points) to do the correct process and place this into the correct cells in the `.csv` file. In my code `row[4]` = Goals for, `row [5]` = Goals against, `row[1]` = wins and `row[2]` = draws.

```
codebox("This teams current league positioning is as follow:", title, y + "\n" + x)
        msg = "What do you wish to change?"
        title = "League change"
        fields = ["Team name("+row[0]+")", "W("+row[1]+")", "D("+row[2]+")", "L("+row[3]+")", "GF("+row[4]+")", "GA("+row[5]+")"]
        x = int(row[4])
        y = int(row[5])
        row[6] = x - y
        row[7] = (row[1]*3) + row[2]
        reply = multenterbox(msg,title,fields)
        table_n.writerow(reply) + str(row[6]) + str(row[7])            
    else:
        table_n.writerow(row)
```

The error I get here is as follows:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the line just before the `else` be `table_n.writerow(reply + str(row[6]) + str(row[7]))`? Note the change in the parenthesis.

Comment: The error clearly says, that the + operand does not work for NoneType and str. I am not sure what is in all the row but eitehr the problem is in line 4 because something is None or in line 10 because the syntax in teh line looks weird

Comment: I previously had your suggestion Hernan but got a different error message come up

Comment: The current error is definitely caused by the fact that you're trying to append strings to the output of `table_n.writerow(reply)` which is `None`.  What error were you getting before, when you had the code as @HernánErasmo suggests?

Comment: table_n.writerow(reply + str(row[6]) + str(row[7])) leads to this error:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 1):

I believe easygui's`multenterbox()`returns a list of the values of the fields which, from your code looks like they're the elements 0-5 of the row. What you need to do to write them plus what's in rows 6-7 in the`writerow()`call. This can be done by combining these last two into a list, adding them to the reply list, and passing that to`writerow()`:

```
table_n.writerow(reply + [str(row[6]), str(row[7])])
```

I'm not sure the calls to`str()`are necessary.

Comment: I attempted this but the .csv was not updated, no error message came up but it did not have the desired effect.

Comment: Did you actually look at the text of the csv file? I can't tell from the snippet of code in your question exactly what you're doing, however I'm not so sure you can just add a couple of columns to a row in the middle of csv file.

Comment: Yes, I went in and checked the data in my csv file and it did not update. Basically, I am attempting to take the data provided from the user and process this in to goal difference and points by using the wins, draws, goals for and against fields but this does not occur

Comment: Well, sounds like something's wrong with the data in `reply + [str(row[6]), [str(row[7])]`. Trying printing it out separately. You can print to a console window if you start your script manually by typing in `python my_scripts_name.pyw` at the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in that you are trying to add strings to the return value of `table_n.writerow(reply)`, which is probably None. What you want to do is add the strings together
`table_n.writerow(reply + str(row[6]) + str(row[7]))`

Comment: table_n.writerow(reply + str(row[6]) + str(row[7])) leads to this error:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list